# I tried installing IE11, but it seems to be corrupted.

Tags: windows-7, installation, browser, internet-explorer

I tried installing IE11 but I do not think the install completed properly. It's listed as a program under the start menu but not under Control Panel -> Programs and Features. When I try to open it, it loads but doesn't respond and I get this screen:[image]

If I try installing it again, I get the following:
Any ideas of what I should do?
[image]

Comment: Have you rebooted yet?

Comment: whats your windows operating system,it seems higher version already preinstalled with it,

Comment: I have Windows 7 and yes, I believe IE9 was preinstalled on it. I tried uninstalling it at one time in the past but now I need it back for work reasons.